# Deploying the business network using hyperledger composer v16.06

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am a beginner with hyperledger composer. I using hyperledger-composer v16.06.
In step Deploying the business network:

```
composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName tutorial-network

⠋ Installing runtime for business network tutorial-network. This may take a minu
⠙ Installing runtime for business network tutorial-network. This may take a minu
⠹ Installing runtime for business network tutorial-network. This may take a minu
✖ Installing runtime for business network tutorial-network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: The Composer runtime failed to install on 1 or more peers
Command failed
```

And then i try use :

> curl -sSL https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/install-hlfv1.sh |
>   bash

but disply syntax error:

```
curl -sSL https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/install-hlfv1.sh | bash
bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: line 1: `<!doctype html>'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v16.0.6 is an older version of Composer with limited support.  If you are new to Composer I would suggestthe following steps which will install Composer v0.19 and a simple Fabric v1.1:

1. Uninstall Composer (composer-cli) and composer-playground, composer-rest-server generator-hyperledger-composer if you installed them.

   2. Install the Composer development [pre-requisites](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html)
   3. Install the Composer [Development tools](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html)
   4. Work through the [Developer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial)